# PostgreSQL function returns all records

Tags: postgresql, sql-function

How to modify existing function to return all rows from table sd_users?

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getusers()
      RETURNS sd_users AS
    $BODY$
    DECLARE
      groups sd_users;
    BEGIN
        SELECT * INTO groups FROM sd_users;
        RETURN groups;

    END;
    $BODY$
      LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
      COST 100;
    ALTER FUNCTION getusers()
      OWNER TO postgres;
```

Invoke the function code:

```
  SELECT getusers()
```

This code returns only first record, how to make it to return all records?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for [`setof`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/xfunc-sql.html). And it can be plain SQL in instead of plpgsql

```
create or replace function getusers()
returns setof sd_users as $body$
    select * from sd_users;
$body$ language sql stable
```